# Mvc Ajax call to controller not returning statusText

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery 3.2.1 with .NET framework 4.5.2 MVC.

I have an jquery ajax call to an mvc controller. If the action is successful, the return is

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200, "success message");
```

and when it fails,

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "failure message");
```

and here is my javascript call:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/TestAjaxAsync',
    // ...
});

promise.done(function(results) {
    console.log("got success: ");
    console.log(results);
});

promise.fail(function(err) {
    console.log("got error: ");
    console.log(err);
});
```

all of this is working perfectly on local machine in visual studio IIS express, and when hosted locally. I can send the request and get "success message" and "failure message" in statusText property with status code.

But when hosted in production server remotely, this stops working. I am able to send the request successfully and receive the response successfully and get "success message" for 200 OK. But for 400, 401, 403 or any other error codes, the statusText is always "error". Sometimes, the custom message is shown in responseText as a YSOD with full html markup.

I have tried the following also but could not get it to working on production server at all.

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "failure message");
```

Comment: sounds like a server setting for _friendly error messages_ (or similar, custom errors off perhaps) is overriding your status codes. Check settings.

Answer (score 2):

## As by [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});**
>
> An alternative construct to the success callback option, refer to deferred.done() for implementation details.
>
> **jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});**
>
> An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

The first argument of `done(function(...))` is `data`, but the first argument of `fail(function(...))` is `jqXHR`, which..

> is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object

### You should try

```
promise.fail(function (jqXHR) {
    console.log("got error: ");
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

or

```
promise.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log("got error: ");
    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

or

```
promise.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("got error: ");
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

Depending on what works best for you.

Comment: i tried all the above implementations. I am not getting "failure message". instead i always get statusText: "error"

Comment: @HuSen That's.. unfortunate.

Comment: thing is i have been using this practice in almost all of my applications and never failed... until now... very strange indeed

Answer (score 0):

> Add baseurl with your Ajax url parameter.

```
var geturl = window.location;
var baseurl = geturl.protocol + "//" +geturl.host + "//" + geturl.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

url : baseurl + 'controller/action'

Answer (score 0):

try this when it fails:

```
throw new HttpException(400, "bad request");
```